# Copying pointers to a given subclass from one vector to the other one

Tags: c++, vector, stl

I have a problem (as you can guess, becasue I wrote this post). I do have 1 base class and 2 subclasses (Figure, Triangle, Rectangle).

Figure

```
class Figure
{
protected:
    std::string color;
public:
    Figure(std::string color);
    virtual ~Figure();
};

Figure::Figure(std::string color) : color(color) {}
```

Triangle

```
class Triangle : public Figure
{
private:
    unsigned int base;
    unsigned int height;
public:
    Triangle(std::string color, unsigned int base, unsigned int height);
};

Triangle::Triangle(std::string color, unsigned int base, 
    unsigned int height) : Figure(color), base(base), height(height) {}
```

Rectangle

```
class Rectangle : public Figure
{
private:
    unsigned int side1;
    unsigned int side2;
public:
    Rectangle(std::string color, unsigned int side1, unsigned int side2);
};
Rectangle::Rectangle(std::string color, unsigned int side1, 
    unsigned int side2) : Figure(color), side1(side1), side2(side2) {}
```

And in main I created a vector containing a few shared pointers. For example (a shortened version):

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Figure>> figures;
figures.push_back(std::make_shared<Triangle>("Red",4,10));
figures.push_back(std::make_shared<Triangle>("Blue", 2, 6));
figures.push_back(std::make_shared<Rectangle>("Orange", 4, 8));
```

And now the taks is to select only pointers to Triangle subclass (from figures vector) and put them into another new vector (triangles vector).

I have tried a few solutions, but none of them have worked.

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Triangle>> triangles;
    std::copy_if(figures.begin(), figures.end(), triangles.begin(), [](auto fig) {
        std::shared_ptr<Triangle> el = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig);
        return !(el == nullptr);
    });
```

Second

```
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Triangle>> triangles;
    std::transform(figures.begin(), figures.end(), triangles.begin(), [](auto fig) {
        std::shared_ptr<Triangle> el = std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig);
        if(el != nullptr) return el;
    });
```

Probably the frist way of trying to solve it is closer to the right one, but it sill doesn't work.

Thanks for your help

Comment: Please if you have errors do include them in the question

Comment: And you need [`std::back_inserter`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/back_inserter), and you would need (missing) `transform_if`.

Comment: I thought it would need std::back_inserter too, but http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/copy_if/ has a working demo with begin()

Comment: the types are incompatible, as the error message probably says. I was going to say use std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Figure>> triangles, but I bet Jarod42's transform gets what you asked for.

Comment: I would also point out that you don't have to have a lambda. You can define a function "is_triangle" for easier debugging. It will also make you remember you have a shared_ptr wrapper.

Comment: I saw a few working examples with begin() too. Jarod42's transform works well like you wrote. I am trying to use lambdas now, as I am getting familiar with them now.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no `std::transform_if` currently, so you might do it in 2 passes:

```
std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Triangle>> triangles;
std::transform(figures.begin(),
               figures.end(),
               std::back_inserter(triangles),
               [](auto fig) { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig); });

triangles.erase(std::remove(triangles.begin(), triangles.end(), nullptr), triangles.end());
```

Comment: Thanks. It works well. I am just wondering why copy_if is not a proper way to solve it here? Name indicates that it would be a good choice for task like that (but of course it can misleading)

Comment: @JamesSmith the result of the cast is only used to check if the value should be copied. `copy_it` will try to assign a `std::shared_ptr<Figure>` to the proxy returned by the `std::back_inserter(triangles)`, which will fail

Answer (score 0):

You can write a `transform_if`, or a more specific `copy_of_type`

```
template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class Predicate, class UnaryOperation>
OutputIt transform_if(InputIt first1, InputIt last1, OutputIt d_first, Predicate pred, UnaryOperation unary_op)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        auto && val = unary_op(*first1++);
        if (pred(val)) {
            *d_first++ = val;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}

template<class InputIt, class OutputIt, class Cast>
OutputIt copy_of_type(InputIt first1, InputIt last1, OutputIt d_first, Cast cast)
{
    while (first1 != last1) {
        auto && val = cast(*first1++);
        if (val) {
            *d_first++ = val;
        }
    }
    return d_first;
}
```

Which would be used

```
transform_if(figures.begin(),
             figures.end(),
             std::back_inserter(triangles),
             [](auto fig) { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig); },
             [](auto fig) { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig); });

copy_of_type(figures.begin(),
             figures.end(),
             std::back_inserter(triangles),
             [](auto fig) { return std::dynamic_pointer_cast<Triangle>(fig); });
```